# Android разработка приложений. Как узнать отображен ли на экране элемент разметки на экране зная его id

Tags: java, android, мобильные-приложения

Как узнать нарисован (отображен) ли на экране тот или иной элемент разметки на экране зная его id? 
Допустим. Вызывается экран, на котором генерируется: 1) 10 TextView, каждый с определенным, заранее известным, id 2) Одна кнопка 3) Поле ввода. Пользователь набирает в строке "любые символы" и нажимает кнопку, если "любые символы" совпадут с любым из десяти созданных id TextView то появляется Toast "Вы угадали id". Повторю вопрос, подскажите как узнать сгенерировался ли объект с таким id или нет?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

Comment: Как получить имя "String" элемента разметки?

Comment: Это вы о чем? У контролов нет текстовых имен.